# Node.JS/Express/Mongo: TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I've gone searching for other solutions to this problem and none of the solutions I've seen elsewhere seem to work for me. I have a form that I want to submit to a database. I'm using node.JS, express, mongo, and pug to render the HTML.

Here's my form:

```
.modal-content
form(method='POST' action='/insert' id='newReminders')
  input(type='text' name='location' id='location' placeholder='location')
  br
  input(type='textarea' name='reminder' rows='4' id='reminder' placeholder='type your reminder here')
  br
  button(type='submit' id='saveButton') save
span.close-button &times;
```

And here's my server-side JS:

```js
app.post('/insert', (req, res)  => {
var dokoEntry = {
   reminder: req.body.location,
   content: req.body.reminder
 };

 mongo.connect(url, function (err, db) {
   assert.equal(null, err);
   db.collection('reminders').insertOne(item, (err, result) => {
     assert.equal(null, err);
     console.log('Reminder inserted');
     db.close();
   })
 })
 res.redirect('/checkLocation'); 
})
```

Comment: Are you use something like `body-parser` to parse body of post requests?

Comment: On DevTools, check the network request. Click on the request and look at the information on the bottom of the page. The you'll, see the payload that's being sent to the server. Just make sure DevTools are open before you make the request.

Answer (score 0):

The term `location` is a reserved property of The `window` object in browsers. When you define an `id` attribute on an element, the browser will assign the DOM element to a property in window by the value of `id`.

So, for example, for the element

```
<input id="location" />
```

your creating a property accessible via

```
window.location
```

However, `window.location` is a read-only property of the browser.

Try renaming that `<input>` element

Comment: I renamed it "where" and I get the same error message, just with "where" instead of "location" being the problem: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'where' of undefined"

Comment: Rename it `where1`, something less `keyword`-like

Comment: I now get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'where1' of undefined"

Comment: Can you post the contents of the `req` object? Clearly `body` is not a property of that object. Maybe the payload is somewhere else?